# assign a default placeholder value to a dropdown list menu

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to assign a placeholder value to a drop down menu that holds state abbreviations from an entity model.

This is the example code I have tried, but that is not working, because

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateID, new SelectList(Model.States, "ID", "Abbreviations", Model.StateID), new { id = "StateID" + Model.ID, data_placeholder = "State" })
```

When I open the page, the first value that shows is AL for Alabama instead that the word "State"

Comment: Have you tried `placeholder = "State"`? I haven't done MVC in a few years now, so I'm not entirely sure how the `DropDownListFor` functions exactly.

Comment: I did try that but did not work:
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateID, new SelectList(Model.States, "ID", "Abbreviations", Model.StateID),  new { placeholder = "State" })
. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703567(v=vs.118).aspx) overloaded version of `DropDownListFor` to specify default option :-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateID, new SelectList(Model.States,"ID","Abbreviations"),
                           "State", new { id = "StateID" + Model.Id })
```

Also, Please note that there is no need to specify `Model.StateID` again in `SelectList` constructor because automatic selection of dropdown (selected value) will be taken care by first param i.e. `m => m.StateID`.